# .htaccess code to block all .ua domains but whitelist a particular domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm blocking some spam referrers using the following `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ua$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ua/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hol\.es [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hys\.cz [NC,OR]
A few more similar lines
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} slinqs\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

As you can see I have blocked all `.ru` and all `.ua` domains using the code.

The problem is now I want to allow a particular `.ua` domain to send traffic to my website.

How can I whitelist that one `.ua` domain?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow `allowed-domain.com` you could do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !allowed-domain\.ua
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ua$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ua/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hol\.es [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hys\.cz [NC,OR]
# A few more similar lines
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} slinqs\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The `!` prefix negates the regex and without the `OR` flag it is an implicit AND. So, the above states that if the HTTP_REFERER does not contain `allowed-domain.ua` and does contain either `.ru` or `.ua`, etc. then return a 403 Forbidden.

The `L` flag is not required when using the `F` flag (it is implied). Also, you don't need a capturing subpattern (ie. `(.*)`) - since you are not using it.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru/ [NC,OR]
> ```

Note that this is the same as (using alternation):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru(/|$) [NC,OR]
```

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ru/ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ua$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.ua/ [NC,OR]
> ```

And so this is the same as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.(ru|ua)(/|$) [NC,OR]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. You are awesome. I really appreciate all your help. :)

Comment: What if I want to add one or two more domains to whitelist? I want to whitelist one .ru domain too.

Comment: Just include an additional line for each domain you want to whitelist - the same as the above.

Comment: There is no limit as far as I know. (Except that if it's too long it might be harder to read?)